# How to traverse all the column of a current row in a table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row in a table something like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Corredor Feed</td>
        <td>Id Corrdor
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="idcorreo">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="nombre">
        </td>
        <td>Email
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Empressa
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="Empressa">
        </td>
        <td>Pagina Web
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="paginaWeb">
        </td>
        <td>Telefono
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="telephon">
        </td>
        <td>Cellular
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="cellular" />
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="button" id="guardarBtn" value="Save" name="submitme">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to access the value of column number 3 that is email when i click on the Save button.

My script is something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
    alert('yo');
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    tr.each('td', function () {
        alert($(this).html()) ;

    });
    // $(".validate", this).css("border", "1px solid #ddd");

});
```

Js Fiddle for the question is [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dpg0f857/2/)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `td` by index using `:eq()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var email = $tr.find('td:eq(3) input').val();
    alert(email);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dpg0f857/3/)

Comment: can you suggest how i can get all the column values instead of just one

Comment: @Vikram it's best to start a new question for that.

Comment: @Okay I am going to do that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607669/how-to-save-the-content-of-each-column-of-a-row-in-a-jqueyr-array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq()` and `.find()` as shown below :-

```
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
    var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
    alert(tr.find('td:eq(3) input:text').val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also go directly to named inputs with jQuery via attribute searches. For instance

```
var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
```