# How to save the content of each column of a row in a jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an array from the content of a table. The content of the tables looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr  class="rowUpdate">
        <td>Corredor Feed</td>
        <td>Id Corrdor
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="idcorreo">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="nombre">
        </td>
        <td>Email
            <input type="text" value="foo@bar.com" class="validate" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Empressa
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="Empressa">
        </td>
        <td>Pagina Web
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="paginaWeb">
        </td>
        <td>Telefono
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="telephon">
        </td>
        <td>Cellular
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="cellular" />
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="submit" id="guardarBtn" value="Save" name="submitme">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the script that I have written is like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
   var content=[];
    $('.rowUpdate').each(function (i) {

        $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {
            if (j != 0) {

                var input = $("input", this),
                    name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length),
                    value = input.val();
                alert(value);
                content[name] = value;
                alert(JSON.stringify(content));
            }
        });
        //alert(content);
        rows.push(content);
    });

});
```

But when I click on the button to get the content of the columns of the table and save it in an array it shows blank

UPDATED Js Fiddle link is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dpg0f857/7/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `content` is not defined anywhere

Comment: @haim770 sorry its a typo

Comment: May I ask you , what kind of array values that you wanted?

Comment: Look your console output: Uncaught ReferenceError: content is not defined

Comment: @frogcoder if you see in the code I am trying to create an array that will have column name as the name of the input type and value of the column would be value of the input type

Comment: @mgamon it was a typo code and fiddle updated

Comment: something like this:

{
"Id Corrdor": "",
"Nombre":""
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this one. I changed  var content= []; to  var content= {};

```js
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
   var content= {};
    $('.rowUpdate').each(function (i) {

        $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {
            if (j != 0) {

                var input = $("input", this),
                    name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length),
                    value = input.val();
                
                    content[name] = value;
            
               // alert(JSON.stringify(content));
            }
        });
       alert(JSON.stringify(content));
       // rows.push(content);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr  class="rowUpdate">
        <td>Corredor Feed</td>
        <td>Id Corrdor
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="idcorreo">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="nombre">
        </td>
        <td>Email
            <input type="text" value="foo@bar.com" class="validate" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Empressa
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="Empressa">
        </td>
        <td>Pagina Web
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="paginaWeb">
        </td>
        <td>Telefono
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="telephon">
        </td>
        <td>Cellular
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="cellular" />
        </td>
        <td>

            <input type="submit" id="guardarBtn" value="Save" name="submitme">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<form name="form_name" id='form_name'>
    <table>
    <tr class="rowUpdate">
        <td>Corredor Feed</td>
        <td>Id Corrdor
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="idcorreo">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="nombre">
        </td>
        <td>Email
            <input type="text" value="foo@bar.com" class="validate" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Empressa
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="Empressa">
        </td>
        <td>Pagina Web
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="paginaWeb">
        </td>
        <td>Telefono
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="telephon">
        </td>
        <td>Cellular
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="cellular" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="guardarBtn" value="Save" name="submitme">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
            </form>
```

js Here :

```
    $(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
var row=[];
    $('.rowUpdate').each(function (i) {
        var content=[];
        $(this).find('input').each(function(key,value){
          var field_name=$(this).attr('name');
          var field_value=$(this).val();
            content[field_name]=field_value;
        });
        row.push(content);
    });
    console.log(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (keep the HTML the same):

```
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
    var rows = [];
    $('.rowUpdate').each(function (i) {
        var row = {};
        $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {

            if (j != 0) {
                var input = $("input", this),
                    name = input.attr("name").substring(0, input.attr("name").length),
                    value = input.val();
                row[name] = value;
            }
            rows.push(row);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand the question, you just need for something like this (I'm not sure however why you used nested `each` loops - is there any reason of this? Do you have more code in between these loops?)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function(e){
    var content={};
    $('.rowUpdate td').find('input').each(function(){
        content[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(content));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr class="rowUpdate">
        <td>Corredor Feed</td>
        <td>Id Corrdor
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="idcorreo">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="nombre">
        </td>
        <td>Email
            <input type="text" value="foo@bar.com" class="validate" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Empressa
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="Empressa">
        </td>
        <td>Pagina Web
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="paginaWeb">
        </td>
        <td>Telefono
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="telephon">
        </td>
        <td>Cellular
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="cellular" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="guardarBtn" value="Save" name="submitme">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way to access :

```js
$(document).on('click', '#guardarBtn', function (event) {
var content = {};
$('.rowUpdate').each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
       content[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();            
    });
});
alert(JSON.stringify(content));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="rowUpdate">
        <td>Corredor Feed</td>
        <td>Id Corrdor
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="idcorreo">
        </td>
        <td>Nombre
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="nombre">
        </td>
        <td>Email
            <input type="text" value="foo@bar.com" class="validate" name="email">
        </td>
        <td>Empressa
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="Empressa">
        </td>
        <td>Pagina Web
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="paginaWeb">
        </td>
        <td>Telefono
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="telephon">
        </td>
        <td>Cellular
            <input type="text" value="" class="validate" name="cellular" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" id="guardarBtn" value="Save" name="submitme">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```